# onGenericMotionEvent() is not working - why?

Tags: android

I use it like this in my app's activity code

```
@Override
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onGenericMotionEvent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onGenericMotionEvent(event);
}
```

But he can't work normally, Toast can't pop up normally, and the breakpoint can't enter this callback normally, I don't know what's wrong, hope everyone can help me

Comment: What do you mean by _not working normally_? Does it show up or not at all? something else?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I want to do something while the mouse wheel is scrolling, such as Toast in the above code, but I found that onGenericMotionEvent cannot be triggered when using the mouse wheel, I do n’t know why